# in R, how to apply a function that takes a vector as input, where the vector must be built from multiple columns of a data frame?

Tags: r

I suspect this is an obvious thing to do, but I can't figure out how to do it, or find any information that fits my case in this community or elsewhere.

`vs` is the data frame containing the variables:

```
cs <- seq(0,1,0.2)
vs <- expand.grid(cs,cs,cs)
```

[BTW, already at this stage I have a doubt: can the `expand.grid` command be written more efficiently, as I have 3 times the same vector `cs`? But OK, not the main point.]

`fn` is an example of the function taking a vector as input (the actual one is much more complicated, and the vector has length 16):

```
fn <- function(p) {(p[1]+exp(p[2])+p[3]^2)/(sum(exp(p)))}
```

Now I want to apply `fn` to `vs`, basically making the vector to pass to `fn` from each row of `vs`.
For 1 row this is obvious:

```
fn(c(vs[1,1],vs[1,2],vs[1,3]))
[1] -0.3333333
```

But what if I want to do it automatically for all the rows in `vs`?

After consulting the documentation, `do.call` seemed the obvious choice, and indeed when I used the example function (`paste`), it worked:

```
head(do.call(paste,vs))
[1] "0 0 0"   "0.2 0 0" "0.4 0 0"
[4] "0.6 0 0" "0.8 0 0" "1 0 0"
```

Of course it did not work for `fn`, but I figured this was due to the fact that `paste` takes n arguments, whereas my function takes 1 argument.

That's where I got stuck. I thought I could make a new column containing the vectors made from the 3 columns of `vs`, and then just run `fn` on it. But I don't know how to do that. I tried apply, do.call with `c` or with `list`, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN` as 1 to loop over the rows and apply the 'fn'

```
out1 <- apply(vs, 1, fn)
```

as there is only a single argument in the function, `do.call` may not work

---

Another option is `pmap` after changing the arguments of the function from 1 to 3

```
library(purrr)
fn1 <- function(p1, p2, p3) {(p1+exp(p2)+p3^2)/(sum(exp(c(p1, p2, p3))))}
out2 <- pmap_dbl(setNames(vs, c('p1', 'p2', 'p3')), fn1)
```

---

Or another option is to create the function with input as dataset with columns extracted

```
fn2 <- function(dat) {(dat[[1]] + exp(dat[[2]]) + dat[[3]]^2)/rowSums(exp(dat))}
out3 <- fn2(vs)

identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(out1, out3)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(apply = apply(vs, 1, fn), 
       pmap = pmap_dbl(setNames(vs, c('p1', 'p2', 'p3')), fn1), 
       colWise = fn2(vs), 
       unit = 'relative', times = 10L)
 Unit: relative
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   apply 5.148858 5.137562 3.890306 4.237701 2.901886 3.222972    10   c
#    pmap 2.837697 2.752563 2.189115 2.269152 1.963476 1.889337    10  b 
# colWise 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10 a
```

---

Regarding writing the `expand.grid` in a compact way when we want to replicate the 'cs' vector `n` times

```
n <- 3
vs <- expand.grid(rep(list(cs), n))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun , that's great! I thought I had tried apply with fn, but clearly not; maybe I tested it first with paste and when I saw it didn't work I didn't even bother trying it with fn... And thank you too for the neat trick for expand.grid: I thought I could not use rep because rep(cs,3) would just make a single longer vector. Now I know that making cs into a list first solves the problem. Obviously I am still not familiar enough with R's syntax and classes and modes... Again, thank you very much.